# Update a column in Database based on new and duplicate record

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am working on a problem in which i am pulling list of file names from a folder and storing it into a database table,This process will be running every hour so what i need if there is any duplicate file names that got read from the folder then i don't need any duplicate records in the table it will just update the old record but if there is anything new then it will insert the record.
I am using Spring Data Jpa and i know it can be done automatically by using saveAll method but what i need is that if the file is a duplicate then it will update another column "Description" in the table which says this record got update but when it is inserting a new record it says its a new record.

I want to know what is the most efficient way of doing this without using any loop.

Comment: why don't you keep audit log in another table with timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basily you have an async job and this async job exists in the context of 1 or more instances of the application. There are couple of problems you need to look after:

1. The job that is reading the files need to run only on one leg of the application. For this purpose you should use @Schedlock google it.
2. After you read the filenames you need to verify them against the DB. Couple of variants exist for this procedure:

   A) Testing each file would cause 1 select query per file which may be undesirable.

   B) You can select all existing files from your DB and then your job would be to divide the incoming file in two groups - files that exist and files that dont.  Another option would be to select all existing file.

   C) If the amount of filesis so big that you can not effectivly read it at once. You can create a second table "Incoming files" then you persist all incoming files there and then you performa JOIN with the "SAVED_FILES" in order to find out the already saved files.

Comment: Is there is any direct way to know what records getting updated and what records are new? or comparing the the new records with the records in the table manually is the only way?

Comment: When you read the filenames the list containing the filenames is detached. You dont know if a filename exists or not. You need the information from your application. You can find it oút based on the 3 mechanisms I told you. Once you get your list to be managed then you can tell if it is a new folder or existing folder.

Comment: I personaly would go with the two table solution. 1 for incoming files one for already persisted files.

Comment: @Gauravsingh The IDs are in the database. When you read the new files you dont have the concept of ID you only have the concept of filename. From DB point of view it is perfectly fine to have  2 IDS with same filename. Now if you want to make your filename to be the ID that is a different story.

Comment: @Gauravsingh think instead of description column to have createtime and updatetime. Then you annotate via "@CreateTimestamp" and "@UpdateTimestamp" and hibernate will take care.

Comment: @Gauravsingh well if your description field is custom :) you see there is no way to do automate it :)